# Print out a warning every whole second in Matlab

Tags: matlab, timer, setinterval

I am trying to print a warning or just a message after every second, like "1 second elapsed".
Is there a possibility to realize that?

I tried it with tic toc and a loop, but it is pretty insufficient. Furthermore I never get exactly one second. Is there a command that prints every X ms automatically?
Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a [timer](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/timer-class.html) object.

```
t = timer;
t.ExecutionMode = 'fixedRate';
t.Period = 1;
t.TimerFcn = @(~,~)disp('1s elapsed');
start(t)
```

Answer (score 3):

As [@Daniel suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24060589/97160), timer objects are the way to go.

One thing to remember is that MATLAB timers execute asynchronously but are [not truly parallel](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/explicit-multi-threading-in-matlab-part4/#timers) (even though [timer objects run in a different thread](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/94884-is-there-variable-access-synchronization-between-matlab-main-execution-thread-and-spawned-java-threa), the MATLAB interpreter is still [single-threaded](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/use-a-matlab-timer-object.html)).

So timer events might not fire (`BusyMode` property defaults to `drop`) it they occur during certain lengthy non-interruptible operations (like builtin functions, MEX-functions, etc..).

Here is an example:

```
>> t = timer('ExecutionMode','fixedRate', 'Period',1, 'BusyMode','drop', ...
    'TimerFcn',@(~,~)disp(datestr(now,'MM:SS')));
>> start(t)
35:21
35:22
35:23
>> eig(rand(2000));    % <-- takes a couple of seconds to finish
35:27
35:28
35:29
35:30
>> stop(t)
```

Note how the timer event did not get a chance to execute while the `EIG` function was running.

Now if we change the [`BusyMode` property](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/timer-class.html#inputarg_BusyMode) to `queue`, then once again the event will not fire during the execution of `EIG` operation, but will immediately spit out all the queued events once `EIG` finishes:

```
>> t.BusyMode = 'queue';
>> start(t)
37:39
37:40
>> eig(rand(2000));
37:45
37:45
37:45
37:45
37:45
37:46
37:47
>> stop(t)
>> delete(t)
```

Comment: Here is another interesting discussion: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/10394-timer-and-interruptible-off-button-callback-priority-preemption

Answer (score 0):

It is called `pause`. The optional argument specifies the duration in seconds. Documentation: http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/pause.html

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to pause my code. I just want to print out something every second, while the code runs.

Comment: Ok, then I misunderstood your question. You might want to clarify that.